# RxJs - Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Group[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

To get two properties to show in the console, several ways have been tried but without success, currently the following error is thrown:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<Group[]>'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type
> 'Group[]'

Here is the service method:

```
  getGroupsNames(): Observable<Group[]> {
    const groupsSource = from(this.http.get<Group[]>(`this.baseUrl + 'groups/'`)).pipe(
      map(res => {res.map(x => { x.name, x.uriname})})
    );

    return (groupsSource);            <= Error points to this line
  }
```

If the operator map is changed to tap, the data objects show in the console, but properties remain inaccessible, here is the calling code in the component:

```
  getGroups() {
    this.groups$ = this.myService.getGroupsNames();
    this.groups$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res),
      console.log(res[0]),
      console.log(res[0].uriname ),            <= Returns undefined (uriname)
    });
  }
```

What can be the reason ?

**Update:**
My question may have been disappointing, because I have two properties and first I was testing with "uriname" before posting my question with "name", the second one cannot give error.

```
  console.log(res[0].name )
```

instead of

```
  console.log(res[0].uriname )
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return something from `map` operator, and when nothing is returned it have type `void`

So where you have:

```
map(res => {res.map(x => { x.name, x.uriname})})
```

Should be:

```
map(res => {
  return res.map(x => { // <-- missing `return`
    return { 
      name: x.name,  // <-- missing `return` and object notation
      uriname: x.uriname
    };
  });
})
```

Comment: Your suggestion should return Type 'Observable<Observable<{ name: string; uriname: string; }[]>>' which is not assignable to type'Observable<Group[]>'.

Comment: Remove everything, keep only `return this.http.get<Group[]>(this.baseUrl + 'groups/')` and this method will return proper type

Comment: You're right all this struggle was built on a typo matter from the beginning, the property "uriname" was camel case "uriName" in the backend returned result, so now let's try to clean up this discussion to make it useful to others. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't know where was typo, could you also edit an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, why do you use `from`? `this.http.get` should by default returning an observable for you.

Are you able to try:

```
  getGroupsNames(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.http.get<Group[]>(`this.baseUrl + 'groups/'`).pipe(
      map(res => ({ name: res.name, uriname: res.uriname }) )
    );

  }
```

since you are not using `return` in explicit, you need to wrap it in `( )`.

Also, when you did the mapping, you didn't assign `x.name` and `x.uriname` to any property.

I'm assuming you have a `Group` interface with `name: string; uriname: string`.

So, I'll just assign this as part of the map:
`(res => ({ name: res.name, uriname: res.uriname }))`.

Or you can also destructure it if you prefer to make it simpler: `(({name, uriname}) => ({ name, uriname }) )`

Comment: return this.http.get<Group[]>(${groupsNamesUrl}); was enough. Your suggestion gives the following error: Type 'Observable<{ res: Group[]; "": any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Group[]>', I am sorry for the late answer, I was checking the first arriving one. And as you can see all issue was built on the component calling method error, it was obvious that it was a typo in the property (camel case) from the back end which didn't match (all lower case) in the Group interface, but I didn't see that and continued supposing things and trying to find workarounds.

Comment: Ah.. yeah, property mismatch is a tricky one. Glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

My fault:

```
return this.http.get<Group[]>(${groupsNamesUrl});
```

was enough to return a working observable, but using that in the first beginning kept me receiving console error through the subscribing method (please see the component code part in the question).

```
  console.log(res[0]),
  console.log(res[0].uriname ),            <= Returns undefined (uriname)
```

To debug the problem, I tried to use map operator in the Observable to extract the object properties, but could not do that, even by trying other answers here, tap operator was usable but not map, I guess because subscription to the observable had to be done before to use map.

@OlesSavluk answer helped me realize that it was obviously a typo error, the property coming from the back end was camel case (uriName), which didn't match the front end interface property (uriname) witch was written in all lower case.

I didn't see that and continued supposing things and trying to find workarounds.

But now that I replaced the property name "uriname" with "uriName" all works fine.